# Overflow of wrapper and div

Tags: html, css

Being a newbie i'm struggling with the CSS of a site.

I've made an site with a couple of DIV's and wrappers but i can't get the overflow of the inner DIV to stretch the outer DIV (wrapper). I've seen  http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/clearing_floats/example2.php but i'm not able to see my mistake.

Thanks in advance!

```
body { 
    text-align: center; 
    background: url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/background.jpg)
}
#wrapper {
    text-align: left; 
    width: 1250px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 10px;
}
#header {
    text-align:left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 155px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/body2_bg.fw_r1_c2.jpg);
    padding-left: 4px;
    z-index:9;
}
#menu {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
#headerimage {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 268px;
    background: url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/keenfuel_r2_c2.jpg);
}
#mainwrapper {
    text-align:left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 488px;
    background: url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/body2_bg.fw_r    3_c2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#maincontent{
    width: 800px;
    height: 488px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    color: #000000;
}
#newscontent{
    width: 360px;
    heigth: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/news_background.fw.png);
    overflow:hidden;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#footer {
    height: 56px;
    background: url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/body2_bg.fw_r6_c2.jpg);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    clear:both;
}
```

---

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id=header><div id="logo"></div> 
    <div id="menu">

<?php show_menu2(0, SM2_ROOT, SM2_START, SM2_ALL, '<font color="#FFFFFF">  |  [ac][menu_title]</a>', '', '', '', '[ac][menu_title]</a></font>'); ?>

    </div>
</div> 

<div id="headerimage"></div>

<div id="mainwrapper"> 
    <div id="maincontent"><?php page_content(1); ?><br style="clear:both"/></div>
    <div id="newscontent">
<?php

// customized cwsoft-anynews function call
$config = array(
    'group_id_type' => 'section_id',
    'display_mode' => 4,
'max_news_length' => 20,
);
echo getNewsItems($config);

?>

    <br style="clear:both"/>
</div> 
</div>    
<div id="footer"><br /></div>
```

Comment: This isn't related to PHP, post your processed HTML. Maybe even a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

if you strictly follow the link you gave, your newscontent div must become part of the main content div and also your main content must have width=100%. Like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { 
text-align: center; 
background: url    (http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/background.jpg)
}
#wrapper {
text-align: left; 
width: 1250px; 
padding: 0px; 
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
overflow:auto;

}
#logo{
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
right: 10px;
}

#header {
text-align:left;
width: 100%;
height: 155px;
position: relative;
background:  url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/body2_bg.fw_r1_c2.jpg);
padding-left: 4px;
z-index:9;
}

#menu{
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 4px;

 }

#headerimage{
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
height: 268px;
background:     url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/keenfuel_r2_c2.jpg);
}

#mainwrapper{
text-align:left;
width: 100%;
height: 488px;
background:url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/body2_bg.fw_r    3_c2.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
#maincontent{
width: 100%;
height: 488px;
float: left;
padding-left: 15px;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #000000;

}

#newscontent{
width: 360px;
heigth: 200px;
float: right;
margin-top: 20px;
background:     url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/news_background.fw.png);
overflow:hidden;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 15px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
}
#footer{
height: 56px;
background:     url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/body2_bg.fw_r6_c2.jpg);
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
clear:both;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id=header> <div id="logo"> </div> 
<div id="menu">            <?php show_menu2(0, SM2_ROOT, SM2_START, SM2_ALL, '<font     color="#FFFFFF">  |  [ac][menu_title]</a>', '', '', '', '[ac][menu_title]</a></font>'); ?>    </div>   </div> 

<div id="headerimage"></div>

<div id="mainwrapper"> 
<div id="maincontent"><?php page_content(1); ?> <br style="clear:both"/>
<div id="newscontent">
  <?php

    // customized cwsoft-anynews function call
$config = array(
'group_id_type' => 'section_id',
'display_mode' => 4,
'max_news_length' => 20,
);
echo getNewsItems($config);


?>
<br style="clear:both"/>
</div> 
 </div>
</div>    
<div id="footer"><br />
                    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

However if your newscontent div must become part of the main content div are meant to become a sort of table like view and your newscontent should fill up free space at the end - this could be achieved that way:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { 
text-align: center; 
background: url    (http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/background.jpg);

}
#wrapper {
text-align: left; 
width: 1250px; 
padding: 0px; 
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
#logo{
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
right: 10px;
}

#header {
text-align:left;
width: 100%;
height: 155px;
position: relative;
background:  url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/body2_bg.fw_r1_c2.jpg);
padding-left: 4px;
z-index:9;
}

#menu{
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 4px;

 }

#headerimage{
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
height: 268px;
background:     url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/keenfuel_r2_c2.jpg);
}

#mainwrapper{
text-align:left;
width: 100%;
height: 488px;
background:url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/body2_bg.fw_r    3_c2.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position:relative;
}
#maincontent{
width: 800px;
height: 488px;
display:inline-block;
padding-left: 15px;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #000000;
overflow-x:hidden;
}

#newscontent{
left:800px;
heigth: 200px;
right:1px;
display:inline-block;
margin-top: 20px;

color: #000000;
padding-left: 15px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
background-color:#770000;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
#footer{
height: 56px;
background:     url(http://www.keenfuel.nl/v2/wb/templates/keenfuel/images/body2_bg.fw_r6_c2.jpg);
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
clear:both;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id=header> <div id="logo"> </div> 
<div id="menu">            <?php show_menu2(0, SM2_ROOT, SM2_START, SM2_ALL, '<font     color="#FFFFFF">  |  [ac][menu_title]</a>', '', '', '', '[ac][menu_title]</a></font>'); ?>    </div>   </div> 

<div id="headerimage"></div>

<div id="mainwrapper"> 
<div id="maincontent"><?php page_content(1); ?> <br style="clear:both"/> </div>
<div id="newscontent">
  <?php

    // customized cwsoft-anynews function call
$config = array(
'group_id_type' => 'section_id',
'display_mode' => 4,
'max_news_length' => 20,
);
echo getNewsItems($config);

?>
<br style="clear:both"/>
</div> 
</div>    
<div id="footer"><br />
                    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm indeed trying to position the newscontent div next to the maincontent div. If i'm right, it might be the best to use the second option you gave me, but that positions the newscontent div under the maincontent div.